# PHP функция создаёт сессию, но не успевает взять её ID

Tags: php, cookie, сессия

У меня есть функция, которая создаёт сессию в случае её отсутствия.
Сессия-то создаётся, вот только скрипт не успевает брать её ID. $session_id равен пустой строке

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])) session_start();
$session_id = $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];
```

Что можно сделать, чтобы ID сессии брался корректно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант брать сессию не из кука, а напрямую из неё. Кука ещё нет и сначала выполняется ваш php код, а потом создается куки.

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])) session_start();
$session_id = session_id();
```

Comment: Спасибо! Только изучаю сессии, подзабыл про session_id